# How to use "evident"?

Tags: expressions, prepositions

I would like to say "This is evident to me in both my academic and work experience." But I am not sure if I should use "in" here.

Is my sentence correct?

Comment: I think *from* would be a better choice—but it's not possible to tell without more context.

Comment: @Bassford I was trying to talk about the insight I gained. Is it applicable?

Comment: Are you trying to say that you've seen signs of something in both of those things—or that *because* of both of those things you've had an insight? Let's say you read several books and each of them gives a clue to something, and you put all of those clues together to come up with something—you would use *from*. *From* is generally use to talk about something that results in a deduction or realization. On the other hand, if you suspect that somebody who always wears a hat is bald, but you see several photographs of him not wearing a hat—and he has no hair, you could then you could use *in*.

Comment: @Bassford In my context, both cases you mentioned is applicable. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how both could apply concurrently. You'd have to provide more context. what is *that* referring to in your sentence? (Even if it's possible for the two meanings to coexist, one would be more prevalent than the other.)

Comment: As an example, I was trying to say that the trend of digitalization in medicine is evident for me thanks to my study and job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment under the question:

> As an example, I was trying to say that the trend of digitalization in medicine is evident for me thanks to my study and job.

To express this, any of the following sentences would be work:

> Thanks to both my studies and my job, the trend of digitization in medicine has been made evident **to me**.
>   The trend of digitization in medicine has been made evident **to me from** both my studies and my job.
>   The trend of digitization in medicine is evident **to me from** both my studies and my job.
>   The trend of digitization in medicine is evident **in** both my studies and my job.

---

- In the first example, you don't use either **from** or **in**.
- In the second and third example, it's been made evident to you **from** something.
- In the last example, the trend is evident **in** something.

In other words, your own realization comes **from** something. But it can also be true that it simply exists **in** something. The particular viewpoint you view it with will determine the syntax you want to use.

Comment: Thank you! A question regarding "Thanks to": could it be that it is not formal enough for e.g. motivation letter for an application?

Comment: @Aqqqq I don't see anything wrong with using it in an application letter if the tone of voice is similar in other areas too.

Comment: @Bassford What woudld be a case of "the tone of voice is dissimilar"?

Comment: @Aqqqq In other words, so long as every other sentence you use isn't written in a much more formal fashion—making this one sentence stand out from the rest. On its own, I wouldn't consider it inappropriate. But placed in context, it's possible it could be.